# Swift adapt height of view in base of your content

Tags: swift, uitableview, uitableviewautomaticdimension

I have a view like this:

[image]

The label that contains "1 X Pizza wustel" can contains some rows.

Now if the label contains a few row all is ok. But if the label contains more than 3 rows I cannot display all rows.

There is a way to increase automatically the height of the View in base of your content?

Comment: There is. There are many methods, all of which have existed for many years and are thoroughly documented across Stack Overflow and other sites. You can search "Self-Sizing Cells" to get started.

Comment: could you help me because I don't understand what can I do

Comment: Hi @bircastri , you can take a look at this Q&A: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18746930/5492956

Comment: Does it layouts correctly when you scroll the tableview?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's what you want to do - for the constraints of the StackView, instead of setting it "== 80" (or some other constant height), you want to set it to ">= 80", so as the StackView increases from its contents, it can grow along with it.
It should look something like this

[image]

Comment: thanks is are working